# identify selected checkboxes in asp listview object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying to understand the ListView object in ASP but I'm unable to programmatically get the selected checkboxes or iterate through them.  Below are the two methods I'm seeing posted the most here on SO, but so far everything I've tried hasn't seemed to work for me.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

**.ASPX Page**

```
<asp:ListView ID="courseListView" runat="server">

<LayoutTemplate>
<table><asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder">      
</asp:PlaceHolder></table>
</LayoutTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
          <td><asp:CheckBox ID="courseIdchk" Text='<%# Eval("CourseId") %>' runat="server" /></td>
          <td><asp:Label ID="courseTitleLbl" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' runat="server" /></td>
          </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**.CS Code Behind**

```
//Method #1
      string result = string.Join(", ",    courseListView.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                      .Select(chk => chk.Text));
      string result = "";

  //Method #2
  foreach (CheckBox ctrl in courseListView.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
  {
      result2 += ctrl.Text;
  }

  Response.Write("<p>The result is " + result);
  Response.Write("<p>The result is " + result2);
  Response.End();
```

Comment: Is it iterating through the checkboxes in the foreach but not getting their text, or not even doing that?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be even iterating through the foreach.  I put a simple counter in the loop and it comes back as zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not near the Visual Studio but off the top of my head I see 2 reasons why it does not iterate.
1. You should bind this ListView to a source in `OnLoad` method:

```
if (!IsPostback) {
  courseListView.DataSource = GetCourses();
  courseListView.DataBind();
}
```

2. `courseListView.Controls` does not contain items of type `CheckBox`, so `OfType<CheckBox>()` filters out all elements. If you debug and put a breakpoint over `foreach (CheckBox ctrl in courseListView.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())`, you will see that `CheckBox` is one of the subchildren of courseListView., so build your logic depending on which control contain CheckBoxes write the appropriate logic to get it like:

```
    var checkBox = courseListView.Controls.Cast<Control>().First().FindControl("courseIdchk");
```

Again, the code above assumes that checkbox is a child of a control, which is an only child of your `courseListView`.

**UPDATE**

```
var findCheckedQuery = courseListView.Controls[0]
                .Controls
                .Cast<Control>()
                .Select(ctrl => ctrl.FindControl("chkBox") as CheckBox)
                .Where(chk => chk != null && chk.Checked);                
result = string.Join(":", findCheckedQuery.Select(x => x.Text).ToArray());
```

**UPDATE2**

ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="courseListView" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" data-id="<%#((Course)Container.DataItem).CourseId %>" Text="<%#((Course)Container.DataItem).Title %>" runat="server" />
            <br/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:Button runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="True" Text="Submit"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            courseListView.DataSource = GetCourses();
            courseListView.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            var result = string.Empty;

            var findCheckedQuery = courseListView
                .Controls
                .Cast<Control>()
                .Select(x => (CheckBox)x.FindControl("chkBox"))
                .Where(x => x.Checked)
                .Select(x => x.Text);
            result = string.Join(", ", findCheckedQuery.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your observations.  I do bind the datasource, but didn't include that statement.  Sorry.  Let me try your suggestion about doing a debug and stepping through the code to see if I can find the appropriate level the checkbox is at.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, something like this! It's not safe though, small changes in layout - and you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` :)

Comment: Okay, the following finds the first checkbox, so I at least know the child position.
I obviously could build nexted for i... and foreach loops, 
but that seems a little much for such a simple request.
What am I missing?
`foreach (CheckBox ctrl in courseListView.Controls[0].Controls[1].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
              {
                  i++;
                  if (ctrl.Checked)
                        result += ":" + ctrl.Text;
              }`

Comment: Then please elaborate how this checkboxes are supposed to be set to true, I guess, by user and the following form reload?

Comment: The listView is initially populated on the Page_Load event except under isPostBack.  The user is supposed to select any number of the selected checkboxes, submit,  and then my code will continue processing based on values selected.

Comment: Iterate over not checkboxes but their parents with LINQ, see updated answer

Comment: Thank you!!!  That did it.  You saved my day.  I guess I'm going to have to learn to use LINQ.  Now, one last question please.  My goal had simply been to display a list of items with checkboxes to be selected populated from an existing object class.  Should I have used a control other than ListView?  This deep nesting of controls seems so much harder than the way I've done it with much older languages like classic ASP.

Comment: @Trebor You're welcome! Yes, I'd better do it with Repeater, hold on, I'll post it